# Check history previous location before goBack() react router v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

My goal is to enable a "Go Back" button, but only if the route/path the user would go back to is in a certain category.

More precisely I have two kinds of Routes : `/<someContent>` and `/graph/<graphId>`. When the user navigates between graphs they should be able to go back to the previous graph but not to a `/...` route. This is why I can't simply run `history.goBack()`, I need to check the location first.

```
const history = createHashHistory();
const router = (
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/' component={Home}></Route>
                <Route exact path='/extension' component={Home}></Route>
                <Route exact path='/settings' component={Home}></Route>
                <Route exact path='/about' component={Home}></Route>
                <Route exact path='/search' component={Home}></Route>
                <Route exact path='/contact' component={Home}></Route>
                <Route path='/graph/:entityId' component={Graph}></Route>
            </Switch>
        </ConnectedRouter>
);
```

I'd like to implement something like this in the `Graph` component:

```
if (this.props.history.previousLocation().indexOf('graph') > -1){
    this.props.history.goBack();
} else {
    this.disableReturnButton();
}
```

This question also applies to `goForward()` as I'd like to disable the "forward" button if not applicable. Also the user moves around with `this.props.history.push(newLocation)`

Obviously I'd like to avoid using side-tricks like logging in `localStorage` or a redux `store` as the user moves around, it feels less natural and I know how to do it.

Comment: If your history is backed by `window.history`, you can't see what is behind `.back()` or `.forward()` . I'm not sure if hash history is implemented the same way, but I'm quite certain it has the same API, so no luck. I think keeping a shadow copy of history in-memory (your redux `store` idea), is the most pragmatic way.

Comment: How did you solve this at the end? Thank you in advance and regards

Answer (score 54):

While navigating though the `Link` component or even though `history.push`, you could pass the current location to another `Route` component

like

```
<Link to={{pathname: '/graph/1', state: { from: this.props.location.pathname }}} />
```

or

```
history.push({
  pathname: '/graph/1',
  state: { 
      from: this.props.location.pathname
  }
})
```

and then you could just get this location in your Component like `this.props.location.state && this.props.location.state.from` and then decide whether you wan't to `goBack` or not

Comment: Is the state persisted in some way? I mean if the user goes back and forth or several times backwards, this state will work as expected?

Comment: No it won't persist, you will have to make sure you are passing it everytime the uses goes back or forward

Comment: I might as well store locations as a list in local storage or redux store then, but thanks :)

Comment: Sure that is one way to do it, since you didn't want it, I added a router only solution

Comment: Can you do this with Hooks?

Comment: **Update**: yes you can with [useLocation](https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v5-1/#uselocation)

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Can't thank you enough for sharing this, I'd buy you a beer if i meet you irl

Comment: What if while doing this its the state on another page when pulling the location with useLocation or the location from useHistory is undefined. Every time I try to set the state in the push it fails to be set anywhere else.

Answer (score 6):

Using `context` you can store the previous location `pathname`:

```
const RouterContext = React.createContext();

const RouterProvider = ({children}) => {
  const location = useLocation()
  const [route, setRoute] = useState({ //--> it can be replaced with useRef or localStorage
    to: location.pathname,
    from: location.pathname
  });

  useEffect(()=> {
    setRoute((prev)=> ({to: location.pathname, from: prev.to}) )
  }, [location]);
  
  return <RouterContext.Provider value={route}>
    {children}
  </RouterContext.Provider>
}
```

Then, in some component under `RouterProvider`:

```
const route = useContext(RouterContext);

 //...
 <Link to={route.from}>
     Go Back
 </Link>
```