# React router onUpdate only on certain route changes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have this render on my index file

```
render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes}
      onUpdate={() => window.scrollTo(0, 0)}/>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

I need to be able to compare the previous location path with the new location path.

I tried using a variable inside the onUpdate unsuccessfully

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Check this post: [react browser history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47409586/check-history-previous-location-before-goback-react-router-v4)

The current location you know how to get i suppose..

Comment: Yes, the current location I know how to get. I will check the post. Thank you. Edit: I really thought there was something simpler. actually I need to prevent the onUpdate when what changes is the querysting