# React Spring: dynamic values in useTransition() when using it alongside react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-spring

In [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-spring-transition-with-routes-0diem) you can see some nice transition between pages triggered by the route change. (took from [LevelUp Tutorials](https://www.leveluptutorials.com/)' React Animation course, thanks a lot Scott Tolinski).

Now I'd like to make these transitions happen in both directions, depending on which page it's transitioning to (and from), for instance:

- Page One -> Page Two (both pages transition from left to right)
- Page Three -> Page One (both pages transition from right to left)
- etc

From that first example I created [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-spring-transition-with-routes-dynamic-from-and-leave-gxhoy) where the value of `x` is dynamic and should be evaluated to either `100` or `-100`, based on the direction of the transition.

I haven't fundamentally understood how `useTransition()` works, and the [documentation](https://www.react-spring.io/docs/hooks/use-transition) is rather limited. The examples look amazing but are quite hard to understand.

[This example](https://codesandbox.io/s/1wqpz5mzqj) seems to do a similar thing to what I'm trying to achieve but the code feels like black magic: the `y` property of each object returned from `rows.map()` appears to be related to the `y` value on the functions assigned to `enter` and `update` properties because if I remove that I get the error: `Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined`. How does that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has two part.

- determining the direction
- change the animation

I created an example for solving the second part. When the user click page one I reverse the animation.

```
const reverse = location.pathname === '/';
const transitions = useTransition(location, location => location.key, {
  from: { opacity: 0, transform: `translate3d(${reverse ? '-100%' : '100%'},0,0)` },
  enter: { opacity: 1, transform: "translate3d(0,0,0)" },
  leave: { opacity: 0, transform: `translate3d(${reverse ? '100%' : '-100%'},0,0)` },
  // "initial: null" should only disable the 'from' initial transition, not the subsequent 'leave' transition (on the first manually triggered transition)
  initial: null
});
```

Here is the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-transition-with-routes-215t8

For the first part to determine when to reverse the animation, I would store the path at each click and compare the next one to the previous. There is an example of storing the path here: [Check history previous location before goBack() react router v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47409586/check-history-previous-location-before-goback-react-router-v4?rq=1)

I hope it helps.