# React-router: how to check for previous route and change location if their is no backwards route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using react-router to redirect after login but i would like to use `history.goBack();` to route them back to where they came from but if their is no history, say the user came to the login page from another site or cleared browser data after coming to the login page `history.goBack();` won't work, so how would i check if their is a route and if their is call `history.goBack();` if their isn't route to a predestined location like `history.push('/');`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check history previous location before goBack() react router v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47409586/check-history-previous-location-before-goback-react-router-v4)

Comment: their is no valid answer for the question bro.